# JavaFX : how to have my title and menu centered on top of each other [WITH MVCE]

Tags: javafx, menu

I'm new to JavaFX and I'm trying to make a menu that can be any size.

I've tried every layout possible for hours but I can't get a simple design done.

My background is a black Rectangle. I want the title to be centered on top of the screen, and my menu to be centered below the title.
Plus I want the stage size to be fixed to the Rectangle size, so that we don't see white on the background.

Here's my mvce :

```
package mvce_poneymon_menu;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Mvce_poneymon_menu extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        MenuView menuView = new MenuView(600, 600);

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    stage.setTitle("Poneymon");
    stage.setScene(scene);

    root.getChildren().add(menuView);
    menuView.requestFocus();

    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

MenuView.java :

```
package mvce_poneymon_menu;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class MenuView extends StackPane {
    static final Font FONT = Font.font("", FontWeight.BOLD, 50);

    int width;
    int height;

    VBox menuBox;
    int currentItem = 0;

    public MenuView(int w, int h) {
        width = w;
        height = h;

        createContent();
        setOnKeyPressedEvent();
    }

    private void createContent() {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();

        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
        exitItem.setOnActivate(() -> System.exit(0));

        menuBox = new VBox(10,
                    new MenuItem("Start a game"),
                    new MenuItem("Parameters"),
                    exitItem);
        menuBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        menuBox.setTranslateX(360);

        getMenuItem(0).setActive(true);

        HBox title = (HBox)createTitle("Poneymon");
        grid.add(title, 0, 0);
        grid.add(menuBox, 0, 1);

        Rectangle bg = new Rectangle(width, height);
        grid.setTranslateY(25);
        this.getChildren().addAll(bg, grid);
    }

    private Node createTitle(String title) {
        HBox letters = new HBox(0);
        letters.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++) {
            Text letter = new Text(title.charAt(i) + "");
            letter.setFont(FONT);
            letter.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            letters.getChildren().add(letter);

            TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), letter);
            tt.setDelay(Duration.millis(i * 50));
            tt.setToY(-25);
            tt.setAutoReverse(true);
            tt.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE);
            tt.play();
        }

        return letters;
    }

    private MenuItem getMenuItem(int index) {
        return (MenuItem)menuBox.getChildren().get(index);
    }

    private void setOnKeyPressedEvent() {
        this.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                    if (currentItem > 0) {
                        getMenuItem(currentItem).setActive(false);
                        getMenuItem(--currentItem).setActive(true);
                    }
                }

                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                    if (currentItem < menuBox.getChildren().size() - 1) {
                        getMenuItem(currentItem).setActive(false);
                        getMenuItem(++currentItem).setActive(true);
                    }
                }

                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    getMenuItem(currentItem).activate();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MenuItem.java :

```
package mvce_poneymon_menu;

import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.effect.GaussianBlur;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;


public class MenuItem extends HBox {
    static final Font FONT = Font.font("", FontWeight.BOLD, 30);

    private TriCircle c1 = new TriCircle();
    private TriCircle c2 = new TriCircle();
    private Text text;
    private Runnable script;

    private static class TriCircle extends Parent {
        public TriCircle() {
            Shape shape1 = Shape.subtract(new Circle(5), new Circle(2));
            shape1.setFill(Color.WHITE);

            Shape shape2 = Shape.subtract(new Circle(5), new Circle(2));
            shape2.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            shape2. setTranslateX(5);

            Shape shape3 = Shape.subtract(new Circle(5), new Circle(2));
            shape3.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            shape3.setTranslateX(2.5);
            shape3.setTranslateY(-5);

            getChildren().addAll(shape1, shape2, shape3);

            setEffect(new GaussianBlur(2));
        }
    }

    public MenuItem(String name) {
        super(15);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        text = new Text(name);
        text.setFont(FONT);
        text.setEffect(new GaussianBlur(2));

        getChildren().addAll(c1, text, c2);
        setActive(false);
        setOnActivate(() -> System.out.println(name + " activated"));
    }

    public void setActive(boolean b) {
        c1.setVisible(b);
        c2.setVisible(b);
        text.setFill(b ? Color.WHITE : Color.GREY);
    }

    public void setOnActivate(Runnable r) {
        script = r;
    }

    public void activate() {
        if (script != null) {
            script.run();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is very simple but I can't figure it out :c

Comment: unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them - your's is nearly perfect, just the class name with underscores is hurting the reader's eye :)

Comment: It's a package right ? Not a class :o
I don't know, I'm using a Checkstyle configuration based on Google coding conventions, and no rings are belling when I use underscores in package names, is it not conventional ?

Comment: what I meant is the name of your application class, it violates the rule _Names of class types should be descriptive nouns or noun phrases, not overly long, in mixed case with the first letter of each word capitalized._ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html (plus no underscores which are technically allowed but as per convention should be used only if an identifier otherwise is ambiguous or formally invalid)

Comment: Oh yeah right, I do know that, but since that was a mvce I didn't care much. I'll be more careful next time, sorry for your eyes lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My background is a black `Rectangle`. [...] Plus I want the stage size to be fixed to the `Rectangle` size, so that we don't see white on the background.

It would be much simpler to simply assign a background to the `StackPane`. This would allow you to resize `MenuView` and keep the size of the background the same as the size of the `MenuView` without additional logic.

Preventing resizing of the window should be done for the `Stage` using `setResizable`.

> I want the title to be centered on top of the screen, and my menu to be centered below the title.

You're using an "unhealthy" amount of transformation properties. (I'm refering to `translateX` and `translateY` in this case.) These properties are not taken into account by the parent layout; during the layout the nodes are positioned where the same node without any transformation would be positioned and the rendering algorithm considers those transformations though.

Imho the following structure would suit the desired outcome better:

```
MenuView (root)
  |- VBox (place menu items below title)
      |- HBox (title container) 
          |- ...
      |- MenuItem
      |- MenuItem
      |- MenuItem
```

To get the correct size for the title container, I recommend using a padding around the content.

There are several other things that I'd change:

- ```
  Shape shape1 = Shape.subtract(new Circle(5), new Circle(2));
  shape1.setFill(Color.WHITE);
  ```

  I'd recommend changing this to circles with a stroke instead oc intersecting shapes.
- Instead of blurring every child in `MenuItem` seperatly I'd recommend applying a blur on the item itself.
- The `TriCircle` class does not contain any logic other than setting up the nodes. It could (and should) be replaced by a method creating a `Group` containing the circles.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    MenuView menuView = new MenuView(600, 600);
    Scene scene = new Scene(menuView);

    stage.setTitle("Poneymon");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    menuView.requestFocus();

    stage.setResizable(false); // prevent resizing of stage
    stage.show();
}
```

```
public class MenuView extends StackPane {

    static final Font FONT = Font.font("", FontWeight.BOLD, 50);
    int currentItem = 0;

    public MenuView(int w, int h) {
        setPrefSize(w, h);

        createContent();
        setOnKeyPressedEvent();
    }

    private List<MenuItem> menuItems;

    private void createContent() {

        MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
        exitItem.setOnActivate(() -> Platform.exit());

        menuItems = Arrays.asList(
                new MenuItem("Start a game"),
                new MenuItem("Parameters"),
                exitItem);

        VBox container = new VBox(10, createTitle("Poneymon"));
        container.getChildren().addAll(menuItems);
        container.setMaxSize(USE_PREF_SIZE, USE_PREF_SIZE);

        getMenuItem(0).setActive(true);

        setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        getChildren().add(container);
    }

    private Node createTitle(String title) {
        final double movement = 25;
        HBox letters = new HBox();
        letters.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // add space on top equla to the upwards movement of the letters
        letters.setPadding(new Insets(movement, 0, 0, 0));

        for (int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++) {
            Text letter = new Text(title.charAt(i) + "");
            letter.setFont(FONT);
            letter.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            letters.getChildren().add(letter);

            TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(2), letter);
            tt.setDelay(Duration.millis(i * 50));
            tt.setToY(-movement);
            tt.setAutoReverse(true);
            tt.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE);
            tt.play();
        }

        return letters;
    }

    private MenuItem getMenuItem(int index) {
        return menuItems.get(index);
    }

    private void setOnKeyPressedEvent() {
        this.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP) {
                    if (currentItem > 0) {
                        getMenuItem(currentItem).setActive(false);
                        getMenuItem(--currentItem).setActive(true);
                    }
                }

                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN) {
                    if (currentItem < menuItems.size() - 1) {
                        getMenuItem(currentItem).setActive(false);
                        getMenuItem(++currentItem).setActive(true);
                    }
                }

                if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    getMenuItem(currentItem).activate();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class MenuItem extends HBox {

    static final Font FONT = Font.font("", FontWeight.BOLD, 30);

    private Group c1 = createTriCircle();
    private Group c2 = createTriCircle();
    private Text text;
    private Runnable script;

    private static Circle createCircle(double centerX, double centerY) {
        final double innerRadius = 2;
        final double outerRadius = 5;
        Circle circle = new Circle(centerX, centerY, (innerRadius + outerRadius) / 2, null);
        circle.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
        circle.setStrokeWidth(outerRadius - innerRadius);
        return circle;
    }

    private static Group createTriCircle() {
        return new Group(
                createCircle(0, 0),
                createCircle(5, 0),
                createCircle(2.5, -5));
    }

    public MenuItem(String name) {
        super(15);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        text = new Text(name);
        text.setFont(FONT);

        setEffect(new GaussianBlur(2));

        getChildren().addAll(c1, text, c2);
        setActive(false);
        setOnActivate(() -> System.out.println(name + " activated"));
    }

    public void setActive(boolean b) {
        c1.setVisible(b);
        c2.setVisible(b);
        text.setFill(b ? Color.WHITE : Color.GREY);
    }

    public void setOnActivate(Runnable r) {
        script = r;
    }

    public void activate() {
        if (script != null) {
            script.run();
        }
    }
}
```

To adjust the distance between title and menu items, you could use `VBox.setMargin`.

Comment: Thank you it works well, that's exactly what I was looking for !